# Call an object in another method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to use an object of a method in an another method.
How can i do this ?

I got an object named "cell". I custom it in cellForRowAtIndexPath.
I want to custom it in didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Thanks for help!

Flo

Comment: Please put your question clearly. What does it mean by "custom it in cellForRowAtIndexPath "?

Comment: It it possible to use [performSelector](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html) in this case?

Comment: It means that i put a background color, and other stuff like that. When i click on a cell in my TableView i want to change the background of the cell but in didSelectedRowatIndexPath.

Comment: Might be worth doing a basic Objective-C tutorial before going out to the community for assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the selected cell in didSelectRowAtIndexPath as

```
YourCustomCell *selectedCell = (YourCustomCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

EDIT:

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    YourCustomCell *selectedCell = (YourCustomCell *) [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    selectedCell.selected = YES; // Calls setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated function of table view cell.
}
```

Following should be in your table view cell class.

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    // Configure the view for the selected state
    if (selected) {
        // set background for selected state...
    }else {
        // set background for unselected state...
    }

    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
}
```

Comment: Thanks that's what i want.
But now when i select a cell and i want to change of cell the first stay selected.

Comment: Sorry, cannot get you. Can you please explain.

Comment: I got a tableview with tableviewcell inside.
When a select a cell the background change : that's what i want.
But when i select an another cell i got two cell selected : the first one and the new one.
I want that the first one back to her first custom (cellForRowIndexPath)

Comment: Are you doing cell.selected = YES and then using -(void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated function to change the background? If yes, then you can unselect all the cells and then you say cell.selected = YES

Comment: No i'm not.
I change the background in didSelectedRowatIndexPath
But when it's changed i can't change to the initial background.

Comment: I can't take your code in mine because i use indexpath.row to set the good background.
Or i just miss something.

Comment: You only need to set your background for selected state and unselected state in function setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated. And just use my code. If you havent succeeded yet, then try it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a global variable that changes when you press `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. Then when you've changed that variable, call `[theTableView reloadData]`. This forces the `UITableView` to reload all cells that can be seen (which calls `cellForRowAtIndexPath` again).

If you're trying to add a check box or something like that you might want to add a `NSMutableArray` and store the boolean values for each cell in there and use the parameter `indexPath.row` to find out which object you need to change in that array when calling `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.